# Toggling Textview Color on click in android

Tags: android, colors, onclick, toggle

I am developing my first android app and it is a very basic todo list app.
I have used SQLite database to store the tasks. The added taskes are displayed on the main activity.

I want the user to be able to click on any task to mark it done, and hence the task must change its color to red.

If the user clicks the same task again, it should revert back to it's original color.

I tried to add an onclick listener like this :

```
 public void onTaskDone(View view){
        view.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
```

but the setTextColor method appears in red (that means it can't be done like this).

Please Help !!

Comment: This is for changing the text of button but you can use same approach and where it  changes the text you change the color. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297159/change-button-text-and-action-android-development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
boolean isSelected =false 

public void onTaskDone(View view){
    if(!isSelected){
        view.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        isSelected = true;
    }else{
        view.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        isSelected = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked!! but when I click any task in my todo list, all the tasks switch color, instead of just the one I am clicking.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply achieve this by adding onclick Listener and in that you can change the text color

```
  tvStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(tvStatus.getCurrentTextColor()==Color.BLACK)
                    tvStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED);   
                }else{
                    tvStatus.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: It's more  perfect .

Answer (score 1):

In a single textview click listener we can change the color like below.i having the  adapter class i want to click the particular position textview need to change the color when i click....

```
holder.statusText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           if (holder.statusText.getCurrentTextColor() == context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSkyBlue)) {
               holder.statusText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

           } else {
               holder.statusText.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSkyBlue));

           }
       }
   });
```

Its really worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 boolean isSelected =false;
    public void onTaskDone(TextView view){
        view.setTextColor(isSelected?Color.BLACK:Color.RED);
        isSelected = !isSelected;

    }
```