# The Text doesn't change in Real Time

Tags: android

Goal:
After pressing the button, the text should be changed to the text "TEST" in real time.

Problem:
Based on the code and the advice from the link ([Change button text and action - android development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297159/change-button-text-and-action-android-development)) it doesn't change the text in realtime. You have to press twice in order to the button's text to be changed.

Info:
*I'm new in Android

Thank you!

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNew"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="test1"
    android:text="Button"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="64dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="157dp" />
```

```
package com.jfdimarzio.test1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    public void test1(View v)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNew);
        int count = 1;

        btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                test2(v);

                btn.setText("test");
            }
        });
    }

    public void test2()
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void test2(View v)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test 22", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML has already configured the `test1` method to essentially act as an `OnClickListener.onClick()` method for that button, so just change that method to something like this:

```
public void test1(View v)
{ 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    ((Button)v).setText("test");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In your xml file you define `android:onClick="test1"` so after you tap the button `test1()` is invoked and in it you define a new `onClickListener` which will be invoked thereafter everytime you press the button. So the 1st time you don't set the text test.

Move below code in onCreate:

```
final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNew);
int count = 1;

btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        test2(v);

        btn.setText("test");
    }
});
```

In general avoid to define listeners in xml, like: android:onClick="test1".
Do it by code.

Comment: Thank you for your help!